# How to extract the keyword from str?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am using python3 right now. I got a string over here.
How do i print the -57 which is the 5th number counting from right('-' means no valid value)and print it.
I have tried the many ways but don't work for me.
Thank you guys.

> 525,03,4A5E31F,32,1850,3,5,5,A85E,-87,-8,-57,13,255,80,-

```
print(text[-5]) will this work?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the sting after each ',' and print the 5th to last element.

```
my_str = '525,03,4A5E31F,32,1850,3,5,5,A85E,-87,-8,-57,13,255,80,-'
print(my_str.split(',')[-5])
```